# Como aplicar a função `join` (dplyr) em uma lista?

Tags: r

Tentei de muitos modos aplicar as funções `join` do *package* `dplyr` em uma lista mas não consigo fazer isto. Com a função `Reduce` e `merge` isto é fácil de ser feito, mas, minha intenção é fazer isso com `join` por ser esta uma função mais rápida.

Com `Reduce` e `merge` o código fica assim:

```
newdata <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all = FALSE, by = 'row.names', 
                                      incomparables = NA, sort = FALSE),
                  mylist)
```

O objetivo seria juntar os `data.frames` de `mylist` em um único banco de dados.

`dput` (lista) para auxílio na resposta:

```
mylist=structure(list(period1 = structure(list(sell = 
c(954.82455776073, 
510.810676729307, 744.75243431516, 740.655287634581, 993.685934110545, 
866.834087180905, 523.575691389851, 764.874521177262, 
817.054593935609, 
518.385569332168, 531.494156224653, 843.328540329821, 
795.584754319862, 
938.056216109544, 710.636245436035, 997.307573445141, 
869.842965039425, 
771.45393146202, 823.295841924846, 601.494735921733), place = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("sell", 
"place"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame"), period10 = 
structure(list(
sell = c(733.160433010198, 965.176168596372, 773.615662241355, 
871.220104396343, 850.882120081224, 548.022049595602, 
621.362034813501, 
814.990229788236, 549.271885422058, 695.817611529492, 
881.452074856497, 
993.035112507641, 771.279759705067, 992.838160018437, 
774.461645982228, 
517.854797886685, 637.189441244118, 623.788836062886, 
780.715740052983, 
712.462180759758), place = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sell", 
"place"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame"), period11 = 
structure(list(
sell = c(533.743410953321, 773.384398664348, 872.096808976494, 
842.97708561644, 666.135999024846, 693.793271319009, 863.513759453781, 
539.360933355056, 997.354788240045, 752.822959562764, 
671.030344441533, 
731.102725607343, 580.205574864522, 667.002705973573, 
630.402681184933, 
899.911671527661, 872.772023198195, 543.33548923023, 682.689820649102, 
778.205765294842), place = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sell", 
"place"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame"), period12 = 
structure(list(
sell = c(947.833278682083, 588.600017828867, 992.308593471535, 
763.031872571446, 809.284279122949, 798.120932886377, 
645.494438474998, 
773.96222949028, 880.193093093112, 681.19038187433, 962.226237053983, 
865.827421075664, 837.468956946395, 975.754468236119, 
643.590759718791, 
701.593282399699, 717.885117628612, 986.66607378982, 866.434537689202, 
718.550421763211), place = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sell", 
"place"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = 
c("period1", 
"period10", "period11", "period12"))
```

**Considere `by='rownames'` na função.**

E, embora `mylist` tenha `data.frames` com números iguais de linhas, peço que considere que estes tenham números *diferentes*. Isto porque utilizar `cbind` fará a reciclagem, isto é, a repetição de elementos iniciais de um vetor para completar o outro com número de linhas maior.

Comment: Você quer fazer `join` com o que? O `join` é da lista ou de cada `data.frame` na lista? Caso seja só adicionar as colunas ao lado (o que é sugerido pelo uso de `by = "rownames"`), `cbind()` não é uma solução mais adequada?

Comment: Editei a pergunta. Peço perdão se fui pouco claro.

Comment: Para fins de comparação, poderia compartilhar na pergunta o código que usou para `Reduce()` e `merge()`?

Comment: Coloquei o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), o pacote usado para manipulação de listas é o [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr). Para resolver o problema proposto teremos que usar este pacote em conjunto com o [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

Antes, deixe-me propor uma alteração no código para simplificarmos nossas notações:

```
merge2 <- function(x, y) {
  merge(x, y, "row.names", sort = FALSE, incomparables = NA)
}
newdata2 <- Reduce(merge2, mylist)
identical(newdata, newdata2)
# [1] TRUE
```

No [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) temos as funções `purrr::map()` - similar ao `base::lapply()` - e `purrr::reduce()` - similar ao `base::Reduce()`. Na solução proposta, primeiro criaremos uma coluna com os `row.names` em cada `data.frame`, para depois reduzi-los a um único `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mylist %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, rownames = row.names(.x))) %>% 
  reduce(inner_join, by = "rownames") %>% 
  head()

    sell.x place.x rownames   sell.y place.y sell.x.x place.x.x sell.y.y place.y.y
1 954.8246       a        1 733.1604       a 533.7434         a 947.8333         a
2 510.8107       a        2 965.1762       a 773.3844         a 588.6000         a
3 744.7524       a        3 773.6157       a 872.0968         a 992.3086         a
4 740.6553       a        4 871.2201       a 842.9771         a 763.0319         a
5 993.6859       a        5 850.8821       a 666.1360         a 809.2843         a
6 866.8341       a        6 548.0220       a 693.7933         a 798.1209         a
```

*Nota*: O [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) permite usar essa notação de formula ao definir a função. É só escrever o código e usar `.x` onde deve ir o argumento iterado pelo `map()`.

Já que seu objetivo é acelerar as coisas, como a solução proposta se desempenha?

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  base_reduce = Reduce(merge2, mylist),
  purrr_merge = purrr::reduce(mylist, merge2),
  purrr_join = mylist %>% 
    map(~ mutate(.x, row.names = row.names(.x))) %>% 
    reduce(inner_join, by = "row.names")
)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  base_reduce 2.866133 2.952605 3.040672 2.997764 3.099633 3.458348   100 a  
  purrr_merge 2.887687 3.013930 3.263133 3.086803 3.213559 7.019844   100  b 
   purrr_join 4.994308 5.192140 5.539170 5.309402 5.516985 8.808804   100   c
```

Não muito bem . Isso acontece porque os `data.frame`s usados são muito pequenos e não podem se aproveitar adequadamente das vantagens do [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) e do [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

Vejamos o que ocorre quando temos dados com tamanhos maiores e diferentes entre si.

```
criar_dados <- function(n) {
  data_frame(sell = rnorm(n, mean = 800, 100),
             place = rep(c("a", "b"), each = n/2))
}

set.seed(1)

mylist2 <- list(
  period1 = criar_dados(40000),
  period10 = criar_dados(10000),
  period11 = criar_dados(5000),
  period12 = criar_dados(10000)
)

mylist3 <- mylist2 %>% 
  map(~ mutate(.x, row.names = row.names(.x)))

microbenchmark(
  base_reduce = Reduce(merge2, mylist2),
  purrr_merge = purrr::reduce(mylist2, merge2),
  purrr_join = mylist2 %>% 
    map(~ mutate(.x, row.names = row.names(.x))) %>% 
    reduce(left_join, by = "row.names"),
  sem_map = reduce(mylist3, left_join, by = "row.names")
) 

Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 base_reduce 49.55766 51.29197 56.82020 52.28421 56.13617 206.06183   100   c
 purrr_merge 49.68185 51.34842 53.86253 52.62342 56.48257  64.07410   100   c
  purrr_join 42.35513 43.34814 45.68465 44.27135 47.79180  54.17221   100  b 
     sem_map 20.10655 20.58868 22.42495 21.14190 24.24563  32.57692   100 a
```

Veja que com conjuntos de 40 mil e 10 mil linhas, o desempenho do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) já começa a se destacar.

Vale notar que a comparação do terceiro caso com os dois primeiros não está muito justa porque estamos tendo também o trabalho de criar uma coluna nova com o nome das linhas. Me parece que este não vá ser o caso do uso real. Caso pudéssemos excluir a linha com o `map` da solução (ou seja, contar com o `id` para realizar o *join* no próprio conjunto de dados), como no último caso o desempenho se torna muito melhor.